# How to scrape this table using python and beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://m.the-numbers.com/market/2018/top-grossing-movies , specifically the table into a CSV. I am using Python and Beautiful Soup, but I am very new to this, and would love any tips any solutions. What are some simple ways to tackle this issue?

Thank you

This is my latest experiment below...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://m.the-numbers.com/market/2018/top-grossing-movies').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['filmTitle', 'releasDate', 'distributor', 'genre', 'gross', 'ticketsSold'])

for tbody in soup.find_all('a', class_='table-responsive'):

    filmTitle = tbody.tr.td.b.a.text
    print(filmTitle)

    csv_writer.writerow([filmTitle])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: can you share us your script?

Comment: Sure, this is the middle of my current experiment, I have tried 4 or 5 different ways, I have a feeling I am just misunderstanding something very basic, or missing something simple. Attaching it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the code below would do the job.

Useful links on that topic:

- [Navigation in HTML document using BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names)
- [Reading and writing csv files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Making get request
r = requests.get('https://m.the-numbers.com/market/2018/top-grossing-movies')

# Creating BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# Localizing table from the BS object
table_soup = soup.find('div', id='page_filling_chart').find('div', class_='table-responsive').find('table')

# Iterating through all trs in the table except the first(header) and the last two(summary) rows
movies = []
for tr in table_soup.find_all('tr')[1:-2]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')

    # Creating dict for each row and appending it to the movies list
    movies.append({
        'rank': tds[0].text.strip(),
        'movie': tds[1].text.strip(),
        'release_date': tds[2].text.strip(),
        'distributor': tds[3].text.strip(),
        'genre': tds[4].text.strip(),
        'gross': tds[5].text.strip(),
        'tickets_sold': tds[6].text.strip(),
    })

# Writing movies list of dicts to file using csv.DictWriter
with open('movies.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=movies[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(movies)
```

Comment: I love how clean this is. I am understanding a lot of what you did, but in this format what would be the best way to collect the `movie` url?

Comment: You could get it by finding the `a` tag in the second column and accessing its `href` attribute like that: `movie_link = tds[1].find('a')['href']`

Answer (score 2):

assuming you already have the value of `source`, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(source)[0]
df.to_csv('cms_scrape.csv', index=False)
```